# Solving coupled PDE and ODE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, symbolic

I want to solve a system of partial differential equation in Mathematica.
equation is:

$ y_0 = 0.5, t_0 = 30, λ_{12} = 0.3, λ_{13} = λ_{23} = 0.01, λ_{21} = 2.8 $

I am new in Mathematica. Please help me for solving this system.

[image]

My code is:

```
ind = Piecewise[{{y/y, y > 0.5}}, 0];
DSolve[{D[g[t], t] + 0.3*h[t, 0] - (0.3 + 0.01)*g[t] == 0, 
  D[h[t, y], t] + D[h[t, y], y] + 2.8*g[t] - (2.8 + 0.01)*h[t, y] + 
    ind == 0, g[30] == h[30, y] == 0}, {g, h}, {t, 0, 30}, {y, 0, 30}]
```

Comment: Edit this post and include the code you have tried.  Use the `{}` key to format the code.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 6):

Since the question's PDE is advective, the natural independent variables to use are,

```
{u == y + t, v == -y + t}
```

with inverses,

```
Solve[%, {t, y}] // Values
(* {{(u + v)/2, (u - v)/2}} *)
```

With these variables `v` is essentially a parameter, and the PDE is solved by,

```
int = DSolveValue[{2 D[h[u, v], u] + 28/10*g[(u + v)/2] - (28/10 + 1/100)*h[u, v] 
    + f[(u - v)/2] == 0}, h[u, v], {u, v}]
(* E^((281*u)/200)*Integrate[(-100*f[(-v + K[1])/2] - 280*g[(v + K[1])/2])/
   (200*E^((281*K[1])/200)), {K[1], 1, u}] + E^((281*u)/200)*C[1][v] *)
```

up to an arbitrary function `C[1]` of `v`.  Note that decimal numbers have been replaced by rational numbers for accuracy, and `ind` by `f` for convenience and generality.  Because `DSolve` does not accept the boundary condition, `h[60 - v, v] == 0` (valid at `t == 30` and `30 >= y >= 0`), it must be applied separately.

```
int /. {K[1], 1, u} -> {K[1], 60 - v, u} /. C[1][v] -> 0
(* E^((281*u)/200)*Integrate[(-100*f[(-v + K[1])/2] - 280*g[(v + K[1])/2])/
    (200*E^((281*K[1])/200)), {K[1], 60 - v, u}] *)
```

To compute `g[t]`, `h` needs to be determined only at `y == 0`.  So, insert this value into the previous result,

```
% /. {u -> t, v -> t}
(* E^((281*t)/200)*Integrate[(-100*f[(-t + K[1])/2] - 280*g[(t + K[1])/2])/
   (200*E^((281*K[1])/200)), {K[1], 60 - t, t}] *)
```

and introduce a new integration variable, `τ == (t + K[1])/2`, to eliminate `t` from the integrand.

```
Simplify[% /. {t + K[1] -> 2 τ, {K[1], 60 - t, t} -> {τ, 30, t}, 
    K[1] -> 2 τ - t} /. Integrate[z1_, z2_] :> 2 Integrate[z1, z2]];
% /. Integrate[z1_, z2_] :> Exp[281 t/200] Integrate[Simplify[z1 Exp[-281 t/200]], z2]
(* 2*E^((281*t)/100)*Integrate[-(5*f[-t + τ] + 14*g[τ])/(10*E^((281*τ)/100)), 
   {τ, 30, t}] *)
```

Next, insert that result, which  is `h[t, 0]` into the ODE for `g` from the question, multiple the result by `E^(-281 t/100)`, and differentiate.

```
Expand[E^(281 t/100) D[Expand[(D[g[t], t] + 3/10*% - (3/10 + 1/100)*g[t]) 
    E^(-281 t/100)], t]] == 0
(* (-3*f[0])/10 + (311*g[t])/10000 + (3*E^((281*t)/100)*Integrate[f'[-t + τ]/
    (2*E^((281*τ)/100)), {τ, 30, t}])/5 - (78*g'[t])/25 + g''[t] == 0 *)
```

At this point, define `f` is a `HeavisideTheta` function, increasing from `0` to `1` as its argument exceeds `1/2`.

```
Simplify[% /. {f[0] -> 0, f'[-t + τ] -> DiracDelta[-t + τ - 1/2]}, 
    t ∈ Reals] // Expand
(* (311 g[t])/10000 + g''[t] == (3 HeavisideTheta[59/2 - t])/
   (10 E^(281/200)) + (78 g'[t])/25 *)
```

Boundary conditions are `g[30] == 0, g'[30] == 0}`, the latter following from the fact that `g[t]` is identically zero for `t > 59/30`.

```
sg = DSolveValue[{%, g[30] == 0, g'[30] == 0}, g[t], t]
(* -((300 (-310 E^(18349/200) + 311 E^(1829/20 + t/100) - 
   E^(311 t/100)) HeavisideTheta[59/2 - t])/(9641 E^(1863/20))) *)

Plot[sg, {t, 0, 30}, AxesLabel -> {t, g}, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}, 
    ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

With `g` known, it can be inserted into the expression immediately following `int` above, and revert to `{t, y}` coordinates.

```
svp = Simplify[ReleaseHold[
    Hold[E^((281*u)/200)*Integrate[(-100*f[(-v + K[1])/2] - 
    280*g[(v + K[1])/2])/(200*E^((281*K[1])/200)), {K[1], 60 - v, u}]
    /. {g[z1_] :> Evaluate[sg /. t -> z1], 
        f[z2_] :> Evaluate[HeavisideTheta[z2 - 1/2]]}
    /. Integrate[z1_, z2_] :> Integrate[z1, z2, Assumptions -> 0 < u + v < 60]
    ], 0 < u + v < 60];
% /. {u -> y + t, v -> -y + t}
(* (1/2709121)100 E^(-(1863/20) - (281 (t - y))/200) (E^((281 (t - y))/200) 
   (260400 E^(18349/200) - 7868 E^(311 t/100) - 262173 E^(1/200 (18290 + 2 t)) + 
   9641 E^(1/200 (1770 + 281 (t - y) + 281 (t + y)))) HeavisideTheta[59 - 2 t] - 
   9641 HeavisideTheta[59 - 2 (t - y)] (E^(177/20 + (281 (t + y))/200) 
   (-E^(16579/200) + E^((281 (t - y))/100)) + (-E^(1863/20 + (281 (t - y))/200) + 
   E^(1/200 (18349 + 281 (t + y)))) HeavisideTheta[-1 + 2 y])) *)
```

(`Assumptions -> 0 < u + v < 60` appears necessary to avoid incorrect results when performing the integral.)

Recall that the solution `svp` is valid only for the boundary condition `h[y, 30] == 0`, which in turn requires `v >= 0`.  Return to `int` and apply the boundary condition `h[t, 30] == 0` to obtain the rest of the solution, `v < 0`.

```
int /. {K[1], 1, u} -> {K[1], 60 + v, u} /. C[1][v] -> 0
(* E^((281*t)/200)*Integrate[(-100*f[(-t + K[1])/2] - 280*g[(t + K[1])/2])/
   (200*E^((281*K[1])/200)), {K[1], 60 - t, t}] *)
```

and proceed as before.

```
svm = Simplify[ReleaseHold[
    Hold[E^((281*u)/200)*Integrate[(-100*f[(-v + K[1])/2] - 
    280*g[(v + K[1])/2])/(200*E^((281*K[1])/200)), {K[1], 60 + v, u}]
    /. {g[z1_] :> Evaluate[sg /. t -> z1], 
        f[z2_] :> Evaluate[HeavisideTheta[z2 - 1/2]]}
    /. Integrate[z1_, z2_] :> Integrate[z1, z2, Assumptions -> 0 < u + v < 60]
    ], 0 < u + v < 60];
Simplify[% /. {u -> y + t, v -> -y + t}, t < y < 30]
(* (100*E^(-1863/20 - (281*v)/200)*(-9641*(E^(177/20 + (281*u)/200) - 
   E^(1863/20 + (281*v)/200)) + E^((281*v)/200)*(260400*E^(18349/200) -
   7868*E^((311*(u + v))/200) - 262173*E^((18290 + u + v)/200) + 
   9641*E^((1770 + 281*u + 281*v)/200))*HeavisideTheta[59 - u - v] 
   *HeavisideTheta[60 - u + v] + HeavisideTheta[-1 - 2*v]*((E^((281*u)/200)*
   (-260400*E^(1489/200) + 262173*E^((745 + v)/100) + 7868*E^(9 + (311*v)/100)
   - 9641*E^((885 + 281*v)/100)) + (-7868*E^((311*u)/200 + (74*v)/25) + 
   260400*E^((18349 + 281*v)/200) - 262173*E^((18290 + u + 282*v)/200) + 
   9641*E^((1770 + 281*u + 562*v)/200))*HeavisideTheta[59 - u - v])
   *HeavisideTheta[-60 + u - v] + E^((281*u)/200)*(-260400*E^(1489/200) + 
   262173*E^((745 + v)/100) + 7868*E^(9 + (311*v)/100) - 
   9641*E^((885 + 281*v)/100))*HeavisideTheta[59 - u - v]
   *HeavisideTheta[60 - u + v])))/2709121 *)
```

Finally, combine and plot the two parts of the solution.

```
s = Piecewise[{{svp, y <= t}, {svm, y > t}}];
Plot3D[s, {y, 0, 30}, {t, 0, 30}, AxesLabel -> {y, t, h}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 60, PlotPoints -> 200, Exclusions -> None, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Much of the mind-numbing computation could have been avoided, if `DSolve` would accept the boundary conditions, `h[60 - v, v] == 0` and `h[60 + v, v] == 0`.