# Looking for examples of numerically solving coupled PDE and ODE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, reference-request

I am about to solve a system of coupled PDE and ODE in thermodynamics. My system is a bit complicated, so I would like to learn from some examples before coding my own system.

I searched this site and found several cases as following

[Solving coupled PDE and ODE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/177281/solving-coupled-pde-and-ode)

[Couple a PDE and ODE in NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121979/couple-a-pde-and-ode-in-ndsolve)

And I would like to know if there are more of them, with topic like "Solving coupled PDE and ODE numerically".

If you know a good example, please post its link, and I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show your equations, and appropriate conditions.

Comment: I have listed several more in Wiki answer, in the hopes that others will add more.  The problem with my list is that most were not answered, in some cases because the questions were incomplete.  As noted by @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ, providing the equations would allow readers to provide more specific advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are six more (too many for a comment):

[NDSolve: Couple ODE and PDE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46146/1063)

[NDSolve two PDE plus one ODE, together](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22189/1063)

[NDSolve a system of one PDE coupled with an ODE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145552/1063)

[Simulating a combination of PDEs and ODEs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/182702/1063)

[PDE: Specify AccuracyGoal, StepSize, and WorkingPrecision interval-wise](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116287/1063)

[Using NDSolveValue to solve a 1-D PDE with nonlinear boundary condition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/223274/1871)

Unfortunately, most do not have answers.

Comment: Thank you for your links!