# Numerically solve of a system of PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I am studying the vibrations of a beam which is coupled to piezoelectric strips. This system is described by the following system of DEs:

```
YI*D[w[x, t], {x, 4}] - N0*Cos[2*omega*t]*D[w[x, t], {x, 2}] + c*D[w[x, t], t] + rhoA*D[w[x, t], {t, 2}] + C1*v[t] == 0
Cp*D[v[t], t] + 1/R*v[t] == C2*((D[w[x, t], x,t] /. x -> 0) - (D[w[x, t], x,t] /. x -> ell))
```

where "w(x,t)" stands for the beam's vibration and "v(t)" means the electric voltage. All the other parameters are constant. Since Maple cannot handle this problem, I have decided to try it in Mathematica, so far unsuccesfully. However, since I have no experience with this software, I am not sure if, as for Maple, Mathematica cannot solve my problem, or if my code actually has mistakes. Can someone help me out?

This is my code:

1. Initial commands and packages:

```
CleanSlate[];
ClearInOut[];
with (PDEtools);
```

2. System's parameters:

```
YI = 10000;
N0 = 5000;
rhoA = 150;
c = 300;
omega = 3.2233993;
ell = 5;
Cp = 10;
X1 = 1;
X2 = 1;
R = 1000;
```

3. Differential equations and boundary conditions:

```
pde1 = YI*D[w[x, t], {x, 4}] - N0 *Cos[2*omega*t]*D[w[x, t], {x, 2}] + c*D[w[x, t], t] + rhoA*D[w[x, t], {t, 2}] + X1*v[t] == 0
pde2 = Cp*D[v[t], t] + 1/R*v[t] == X2*((D[w[x, t], x, t] /. x -> 0) - (D[w[x, t], x, t] /. x -> ell))

bc = {w[0, t] == 0, w[ell, t] == 0, (D[w[x, t], {x, 2}] /. x -> 0) == 0, (D[w[x, t], {x, 2}] /. x -> ell) == 0, w[x, 0] == Sin[Pi*x/ell], (D[w[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0, v[0] == 0}
```

4. Solver and graphic output:

```
pds = NDSolve[{pde1, pde2, bc}, {w, v}, {x, 0, ell}, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[w[x, t] /. pds], {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, ell}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[v[t] /. pds], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not recognize `with (PDEtools);` as Mathematica syntax. What does that do?

Comment: @MarcoB  PDEtools is a maple package for PDE extra functions. https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=PDEtools  I have no idea why OP is trying to use it inside Mathematica.

Comment: @Nasser Ah! I see. Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/188197/1871

Answer (score 3):

As noted by xzczd in a comment above, there are multiple methods for solving problems involving coupled PDE-ODE systems of equations.  Here, the coupling, `X1*X2`, between `w` and `v` is very weak for the parameters in the question, and the system can be solved iteratively.  In fact, to be able even to see the effect of the coupling, I have increased `X2` to `1000`.  The iteration proceeds as follows.

First, compute `w` with no coupling to `v`, and from  it the first approximation to `v`.

```
YI = 10000; N0 = 5000; rhoA = 150; c = 300; omega = 3.2233993; ell = 5; Cp = 10;
X1 = 1; X2 = 1000; R = 1000;

pde1 = YI*D[w[x, t], {x, 4}] - N0*Cos[2*omega*t]*D[w[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
    c*D[w[x, t], t] + rhoA*D[w[x, t], {t, 2}] == 0;
bc = {w[0, t] == 0, w[ell, t] == 0, 
    (D[w[x, t], {x, 2}] /. x -> 0) == 0, (D[w[x, t], {x, 2}] /. x -> ell) == 0, 
    w[x, 0] == Sin[Pi*x/ell], (D[w[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0};

pds[1] = NDSolveValue[{pde1, bc}, w, {x, 0, ell}, {t, 0, 10}];
plts[1] = Plot3D[pds[1][x, t], {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, ell}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, x, w}, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}, Mesh -> None]
pdv[1] = NDSolveValue[{Cp*D[v[t], t] + 1/R*v[t] == X2*((D[pds[1][x, t], x, t] /. x -> 0) - 
    (D[pds[1][x, t], x, t] /. x -> ell)), v[0] == 0}, v, {t, 0, 10}, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
pltv[1] = Plot[pdv[1][t], {t, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, v}, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}]
```

Next, simply iterate,

```
Do[pde1 = YI*D[w[x, t], {x, 4}] - N0*Cos[2*omega*t]*D[w[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
    c*D[w[x, t], t] + rhoA*D[w[x, t], {t, 2}] + X1*pdv[i - 1][t] == 0;
    pds[i] = NDSolveValue[{pde1, bc}, w, {x, 0, ell}, {t, 0, 10}];
    plts[i] = Plot3D[pds[i][x, t], {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, ell}, ImageSize -> Large, 
        AxesLabel -> {t, x, w}, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}, Mesh -> None];
    pdv[i] = NDSolveValue[{Cp*D[v[t], t] + 1/R*v[t] == X2*((D[pds[i][x, t], x, t] /. x -> 0) - 
        (D[pds[i][x, t], x, t] /. x -> ell)), v[0] == 0}, v, {t, 0, 10}, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
    pltv[i] = Plot[pdv[i][t], {t, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, v},
        LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}], {i, 2, 5}]
```

A plot of successive curves of `v` shows that convergence occurs within four iterations.

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[pdv[i][t], {i, 5}], {t, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, v}, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}, PlotLegends -> Placed[Range[5], {.47, .7}]]
```

[image]

And, `w` from iteration five is

```
plts[5]
```

[image]

Note the slight irregularities in `w`, probably due to inadequate resolution in `x`.  In  fact, `NDSolve` provides warnings of inadequate resolution, which can be turned off, if desired, by

```
Off[NDSolveValue::eerr]
```

I close by warning that too strong a coupling, `X1 * X2`, probably would prevent convergence.  In that case, consider performing the computation by discretizing the PDE in x. This procedure is discussed in [Introduction to Method of Lines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) and illustrated [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175178/1063) for a more complicated problem.