# 1-D PDE with nonlinear ODE as boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, nonlinear, numerical-value, finite-difference-method

Recently, I am trying to solve a 1-D PDE with a nonlinear boundary condition using the function NDSolveValue. However, it seems that MMA (12) cannot solve it directly with some computational issues.

The governing equation along with associated  initial and boundary conditions are
[image]
where C, D, and E are constant and set as 10, 1, and 1, respectively. Note that both conditions Eqs. (3) and (4) for inner boundary conditions are required.
Accordingly, my code is like

```
c = 10; d = 1; e = 1; sys = {(1/r)*D[r*Derivative[1, 0][f][r, t], r] == Derivative[0, 1][f][r, t] + 
          NeumannValue[c*D[g[t], t], r == 1], DirichletCondition[
         f[r, t] + (d + e*Derivative[1, 0][f][r, t])*Derivative[1, 0][f][r, t] == g[t], 
         r == 1], g[0] == 1, f[r, 0] == 0, f[5, t] == 0}; 
      {fa, ga} = NDSolveValue[sys, {f, g}, {t, 0, 1000}, MaxStepSize -> 0.00001]
```

However, MMA said "There are more dependent variables". Is it possible to address this issue or MMA cannot deal with nonlinear PDE?

Following the suggestion of xzczd, I rearranged the code by combining (3) and (4) and the code becomes

```
c = 10; d = 1; e = 1; sys = {(1/r)*D[r*Derivative[1, 0][f][r, t], r] == 
     Derivative[0, 1][f][r, t], DirichletCondition[
     f[r, t] == g[t] - (d + e*c*D[g[t], t])*c*D[g[t], t], r == 1], g[0] == 1, 
    f[r, 0] == 0, f[5, t] == 0}; 
{fa, ga} = NDSolveValue[sys, {f, g}, {t, 0, 1000}, MaxStepSize -> 0.00001]
```

Note that the inner boundary condition is Dirichlet type only herein. But the code cannot be calculated with errors warned by MMA.

Comment: what is the equation for g? If there is none, then g can not be a dependent variable. Also, note that you are using the finite element method and not  a finite difference method. See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html#1993509248) and the paragraph above it. I am just mentioning this because you added the FDM tag.

Comment: your code does not run. gives syntax error. But do you really need all this other stuff , like timing and monitor and all this in order to show what you think is an issue with Boundary conditions? Why not make a MWE that just shows the essential part of the problem. Anything else you can remove as not needed.

Comment: Seems that you've copied the code in wrong way. (You should not select "Copy As -> Plain Text". Things like `Derivative[……]` won't be copied correctly in this way. )  Please Ctrl+Shift+I to convert the code to input form, and Ctrl+C to copy it, for more info check this post: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1585/1871  @user21 I think we can eliminate $g$ using $(3)$ and $(4)$.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the format of the code.

Comment: @xzczd if eliminate g using both (3) and (4), how to preserve the initial condition in Eq. (6)?

Comment: like User21 said, you have $g(t)$ there which is not defined. This is numerical solver after all. It needs to know what $g(t)$ is. You can't just plugin in arbitrary functions in numerical solvers like you could do with symbolic ones like `DSolve`.

Comment: The g function is to reflect the mixing effect representing something gradually releasing to the flux at r = 1. This function also obey the nonlinear relationship shown in (4). Besides, g only depends on time.

Comment: It's not hard to notice $(2)$ and $(6)$ is inconsistent. Of course this is not rare in practice, if I guess it right, $(6)$ has actually provided a condition modifying the i.c. near  $r=1$.

Comment: Yes, it implies something is instantaneously injected into the location r = 1 the stop in physical problem. With the g of unit value, g act like a source recharge at r = 1.

Comment: Also, it's not hard to notice this system actually has 2 solutions. (Just eliminate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ from $(3)$ and $(4)$. ) Which one is the desired one? Or both?

Comment: I think this way can keep the effects of both (3) and (4) on the model by eliminating df/dr at r = 1.

Answer (score 7):

`NDSolve` currently can't handle [coupled PDE and ODE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/188197/1871), so let's discretize the system all by ourselves, but before that, I'd like to point out the system actually has two solutions. By eliminating $\frac{∂f}{∂r}$ from $(3)$ and $(4)$ we obtain:

```
c = 10; d = 1; e = 1;
With[{f = f[r, t], g = g[t]}, 
 bc = {D[f, r] == c D[g, t], f - (d - e D[f, r]) D[f, r] == g} /. r -> rL;
 bcR = f == 0 /. r -> rR;
 ic = {f == 0, g == 1} /. t -> 0;
 eq = D[f, t] == 1/r D[r D[f, r], r];
 newbceq = Equal @@@ Flatten@Solve[Eliminate[bc, D[f, r] /. r -> rL], D[g, t]]]
(*
  {g'[t] == 1/20 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 f[rL, t] + 4 g[t]]), 
   g'[t] == 1/20 (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 f[rL, t] + 4 g[t]])}
*)
```

It's clear each element of `newbceq` leads to a solution. We choose the first one to continue ([`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) has been used for discretization):

```
points = 25; domain = {rL, rR} = {1, 5};
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 2;
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[f[r, t], t, grid, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ode = ptoofunc[eq] // del;
odebcL = ptoofunc@{bc[[1]], newbceq[[1]]}

odebcR =ptoofunc@bcR
odeic = {ptoofunc[ic[[1]]] // del, ic[[2]]};
{sollst, solg} = 
 NDSolveValue[{ode, odebcL, odebcR, odeic}, {f /@ grid, g}, {t, 0, 10}]

solg // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

```
solf = rebuild[sollst, grid, 2]

Plot3D[solf[r, t], {r, rL, rR}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Using `newbceq[[2]]` instead of `newbceq[[1]]` in code above we can obtain another solution:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's an amazing work! I'll try this.