# NDSolveValue for 2-D heat equation (PDE) coupled with ODE boundary and DiracDelta function

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Recently, I am studying on the point source problem (PDE with DiracDelta) for heat equation.
The equations are as follow
[image]

The problems are arisen from not only the DiracDelta issues but the nonlinear boundary condition at X = 0.

But I still try to using numerical method to solve, and the code is given below

```
 RegularizedDelta[Gamma_, X_List, Xs_List] := 
     Piecewise[{{Times @@ 
         Thread[1/(4 Gamma) (1 + Cos[Pi/(2 Gamma) (X - Xs)])], 
        And @@ Thread[RealAbs[X - Xs] <= 2 Gamma]}, {0, True}}]; 

Timing[
    a=2;b=15;c=25;A=1000;
     Monitor[AbsoluteTiming[sys =
        {
    D[rou[X,Y,T],T]==D[rou[X,Y,T],X,X]+D[rou[X,Y,T],Y,Y], 
     + a*RegularizedDelta[0.01, {X}, {1}]*RegularizedDelta[0.01, {Y}, {0}] -
            NeumannValue[b*rou[X,Y,T]-phi[T], X == 0],
         rou[X,Y,0] == 0, c*D[phi[T],T]== b*rou[0,Y,T]-phi[T],phi[0]=0
         };
       
       {rou,phi} = 
        NDSolveValue[sys, {rou,phi}, {X, 0, A}, {Y, 0, A}, {T, 0, 1000000}, 
         Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
           "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
             "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.009}}}, 
         EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t =. ", CForm[t]}]), 
         InterpolationOrder -> All];], currentTime];]
```

However, MMA gave a warning message:

```
NDSolveValue::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {rou[X,Y,T],phi[T]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined.
```

This problem bothers me for few months. Does anyone have experience to address this issue? Many thanks.

Comment: phi[0] = 0 should probably read phi[0] == 0

Comment: As mentioned under your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/223274/1871), `NDSolve` cannot handle  coupled PDE and ODE.

Comment: As xzczd correctly points out, currently (V12.3) you can not solve ODEs coupled to PDEs. In the [HeatTransfer PDE model tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html#1393540415) there is an example of a similar case and how it is solved with the finite element method, perhaps useful.

Comment: Thank for your kindly replies. Actually I am now trying pdetoode developed by xzczd but facing the memory issue. I will update my code based on this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has not updated the code code as promised

Comment: I decide to close this issue because I solve it in another way and avoid the ODE coupling with PDE issue. So the issue of that becomes minor.